# iOS Swift Textfield Inside Tableview

Tags: ios, swift3, uitextfield, tableview

I'm having three `textfields` inside tableview. I need to set range for each `textfield` like:

`TextField1` -> MobileNumber -> I not allow user to type more than 10 digit

`Textfield2` -> PostalCode -> I not allow user to type more than 6 digit

`Textfield3` -> UserName -> I not allow user to leave first character as empty

Comment: What is the problem? And what did you try?

Comment: @MoeAbdul-Hameed How to use `shouldChangeCharactersIn` when `textfield` are inside `tableview`

Comment: One way to do that is to create 3 text fields with 3 different tags, and use the tags to customize the text fields in the way want. It's not the best solution, but it should work.

Comment: @MoeAbdul-Hameed Can you share me any example codes

Comment: I added some code to explain the idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the 3 text fields are in the same cell:

Create 3 different `UITextField`s in the UI Builder and put them inside a cell in the table view.

Click on the first text field and from the attributes inspector set its tag property to 1. Set the tag property of the 2 other text fields to 2 and 3.

- tag 1 for mobile number text field.
- tag 2 for postal code text field.
- tag 3 for user name text field.

Now, in your `cellForRowAtIndex` method and at the index of the cell that contains the 3 text fields:

```
if let mobileNumberTextField = cell.viewWithTag(1) as UITextField {
    // Customize mobileNumberTextField
}

if let postalCodeTextField = cell.viewWithTag(2) as UITextField {
    // Customize postalCodeTextField
}

if let userNameTextField = cell.viewWithTag(3) as UITextField {
    // Customize userNameTextField
}
```

You can achieve the same result by subclassing `UITableViewCell` and making the 3 text fields properties in it.